# Best approach to start a web application using asp.net and sql server

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to develop a web application using asp.net using C# in the front end and sql server at the backend using visual studio 2012 and sql server express edition 2012. The project that I am currently working on is the online blood bank management with admin and user logins.

I have my ER diagram, schema with all the tables ( about 20) ready. I am not quite sure how to start? Should I first concentrate just on the tables,populate and establish relationships, then proceed to front end design with the registrations part and everything else or just do both of them in parallel?
Can someone please guide me through, I am trying to learn application development and this is my first one.

Any online resources for similar sample project walkthroughs along with some explanation will be of great help!!

Answer (score 1):

C# is not the front end. HTML, JavaScript, and CSS will be the front end. C# will handle server side logic, although you may have some logic in the database stored procedures etc. What you need to do is sit down, design the application (think through the parts) and then implement it. This is not something that can be taught or read in a book, you just have to do it many times in order to get the hang of it.

Comment: Mason: Thanks, I d any online resources will be of some help to me to start.

Comment: Sorry, there was an error in my earlier post, I am hoping to get any online resources to start.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. Online resources, academic lectures, and books are not going to teach you the knowledge you're seeking. It's very easy to read some of these things, but the real world is not a book. The only way to learn what you want is by *doing*. So do a little planning, then **do** it, then learn from your mistakes. Do that enough times and you'll learn. The first things you put together will be crude, inefficient, inflexible, poor designed things that may or may not do what you want. But you learn and improve.